# Lighter web browser with IE core?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

I cannot replace IE with Firefox or Chrome completely because some work would be much more convenient using IE because of the native support of Outlook OWA.

However, IE is just too heavy.

Is there any web browser using IE core and is lighter, assuming it supports the full features of Outlook OWA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer is based on the Trident engine.  Wikipedia has a nice listing of [Trident shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#Trident-shells):

- 360 Secure Browser
- Avant Browser
- Bento Browser (built into Winamp)
- Enigma
- GreenBrowser
- Maxthon
- MenuBox
- RealPlayer
- SlimBrowser
- Tencent Traveler
- ThreeTeeth Browser
- TomeRaider
- WebbIE

Comment: @surfasb: What do you mean?  None of those listed browsers are complete browsers in their own right - they are alternative interfaces to the installed version of the IE rendering engine.

Comment: I tried Maxthon, it failed to display the OWA like IE does. However, avant is able to do it.

Comment: @lamwaiman1988 Switch the browser core. (click the lightening symbol on the right of the address bar). it will change to "broken page" symbol. Now, you are using "Trident" engine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the IETab addon for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/miedgcmlgpmdagojnnbemlkgidepfjfi), which would essentially give you the IE rendering engine wrapped in the Firefox/Chrome browser chrome.

Comment: wanted to suggest the same. I use IETab in Firefox, so I do not have to run another browser in case some stupid website runs ok only in IE, I just click one button in Firefox and get the page rendered via IE engine, but still within firefox window.